# UITableView, how to catch the end of animation?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have an UITableView with lot of rows.
It is like an accordion : http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion
Main cells have subcells, subcells have also subcells. So this is a three-levels tableView.

Well, when the user selects a cell, it expands (or collapses) subcells with row animation.
But I need to set the new size of the tableView, and the scrollView.

I do all that stuff in this method :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

The problem :
When the user tap a cell, then quickly tap a sub one, the second animation isn't done, so subcells of the level 2 aren't shown. But the size has been set (taking in consideration that subcells of level 2 has been shown).

Actually I'm playing with time to handle this... but it really sucks.

Here is a sample of my code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Checking with times (with 0,5 second interval in order to be sure that the previous animation is finished !)

// Setting tableView & scollView heights

[tableView beginUpdates];
if(position.isExpanded == YES)
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
else 
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[tableView endUpdates];
}
```

So, I would like to catch the end of this animation.
Or, playing with a kind of semaphore (but i've only 1 process ...)
Any ideas to fix this ?

Please, keep in mind in your replies that I'm really new in iPhone development.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198633/how-can-i-tell-when-a-uitableview-animation-has-finished. Well, maybe that one is a duplicate of this one, but it has the benefit of having a working answer.

Comment: Duplicate and the answer is really bad. anyone reach this question shoudl have a look at [Callback for UITableView animations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802146/callback-for-uitableview-animations) and [UITableView row animation duration and completion callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832474/uitableview-row-animation-duration-and-completion-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation is controlled by a instance of class `CAAnimation`. This class supports a method `- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag` which will be delivered to the delegate of this instance. This information is typically used to get informed on the completion.

In regard to your special request i would have a look at the `UIView` Class reference. There are several tasks that deal with animations of that view - which is the base class of `UITableView`. Therefore anything that is valid for `UIView` should have effect on the table view.

Comment: How do you access the CAAnimation instance that UITableView uses? (in order to set the delegate)

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing as the comment above, anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

In addition:

You can get the animation by checking `NSArray *animationKeys = [cell.layer animationKeys];` and calling `CAAnimation *animation = [cell.layer animationForKey:_a_key_];`. Afterwards you can set the delegate and catch the completion as described above.