# Callback for UITableView animations

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation, callback

Is there a delegate protocol that includes a callback for the end of animated changes to UITableView? Particularly reloadSection/Rows?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there **DOES** seem to be a way to do this (though not nearly as straightforward as it ought to be!).

While there's no **direct** access to some kind of callback, it appears that `UITableView` animations take place within a `CAAnimation`. Therefore, simply accessing the `completionBlock` of the `CAAnimation` seems to give you what you want.

Here's how I got 2 animations to chain in my `UITableView` subclass:

```
#pragma mark - Section expanding/collapsing
- (void)toggleSection:(NSInteger)index {
    int expandedSection = [self ExpandedSection];
    if (expandedSection != NO_EXPANDED_SECTIONS_INDEX) {
        [self beginUpdates];
        [self collapseSection:@(expandedSection)];
        [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
            if (expandedSection != index) {
                [self beginUpdates];
                [self expandSection:@(index)];
                [self endUpdates];
            }
        }];
        [self endUpdates];
    } else {
        [self expandSection:@(index)];
    }
}
```

The code in the `collapseSection:` and `expandingSection:` methods simply adds/removes sub-sections that need to be collapsed or expanded. The key point here, though, is that, when using this code, I am finally able to collapse one sub-section ***THEN*** expand the next sub-section. Before, both animations were occurring concurrently, which was visually unappealing.

I hope this helps you! I struggled through this for a long time, banging my head against the wall until I found this.

This is written against iOS 6.0. I also really hope that some future version makes this workaround/hack obsolete!

Answer (score 1):

It's not the answer you want to hear but no* :(

The table view's delegate will respond to [these methods](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) only.

However, (it's a bit of a hack but) animations are about 0.35 seconds long do you could just call [performSelector:withObject:afterdelay:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-performSelector_withObject_afterDelay_) . . .

*at least not as far as I know . . .

Comment: Is this reliable/consistent? What happens if the run loop gets delayed?

Comment: It's not consistent at all - it's a bit of a hack! If the run loop gets delayed you will get a pause between the animation finishing and whatever action you want to happen.