# How do I wait until a UITableView built-in animation is complete?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
 [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
 [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:1]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

In the above code how do I make the second line execute after the animation from the first line has completed?

I tried this...

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:1]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

and this...

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
{
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
}
[self.tableView endUpdates];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
{
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:1]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
}
```

...but either way the animations are clearly happening at the same time (and really apparent when slow animations is on).

Comment: You can take help from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832474/uitableview-row-animation-duration-and-completion-callback

Comment: It would appear this is how it is done:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802146/callback-for-uitableview-animations

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Thank you Iducool for pointing me to the other question.

This worked...

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:1]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
}];

[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

[CATransaction commit];
```

I didn't seem to require `UITableView`'s `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`.

Comment: If the loaded cell contains a `UIActivityIndicatorView` then the completion block is never called.

Comment: didn't work for me on iOS 9 with reload/insertSections

Comment: @markturnip Did you ever find a solution to this if you have an activity indicator view in the cell?  I asked this here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672868/reloading-table-view-cells-with-an-activity-indicator-view