# UITableView row animation duration and completion callback

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, animation, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to either specify the duration for UITableView row animations, or to get a callback when the animation completes?

What I would like to do is flash the scroll indicators after the animation completes. Doing the flash before then doesn't do anything. So far the workaround I have is to delay half a second (that seems to be the default animation duration), i.e.:

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newRows
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView performSelector:@selector(flashScrollIndicators)
                     withObject:nil
                     afterDelay:0.5];
```

Comment: I haven't tried myself, but maybe this could do it, with some index path handling: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nowadays if you want to do this there is new function [starting from iOS 11](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2887515-performbatchupdates):

```
- (void)performBatchUpdates:(void (^)(void))updates 
                 completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
```

In updates closures you place the same code as in beginUpdates()/endUpdates section. And the completion is executed after all animations.

Answer (score 212):

Just came across this. Here's how to do it:

**Objective-C**

```
[CATransaction begin];
[tableView beginUpdates];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock: ^{
    // Code to be executed upon completion
}];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: indexPaths
                 withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[tableView endUpdates];
[CATransaction commit];
```

**Swift**

```
CATransaction.begin()
tableView.beginUpdates()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    // Code to be executed upon completion
}
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexArray, withRowAnimation: .Top)
tableView.endUpdates()
CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: On further experimentation, the behavior of this mechanism in this context seems erratic at best. Note also that the documentation says that it applies only to animations added after the call.

Comment: Yes, you're right about that. Setting the completion block before the call to insertRowsAtIndexPaths is how it should be done (also added a CATransaction begin/commit to make sure).

This is exactly how I've implemented it in my apps and it works flawlessly. Nice if you want to chain an animation off the insert/delete animation.

Comment: FWIW, this does not work for me. The callback gets hit long, long after the actual animation is complete. (iOS 6)

Comment: Again, works flawlessly here. iOS6 and all. This is a proper SDK-supported mechanism for overriding properties in default animations. Perhaps you have additional, longer-running animations inside your CATransaction? They get nested, you know.

Comment: `setAnimationDuration` doesn't seem to affect the insert/delete duration. iOS 6

Comment: Works fine for me too in iOS 5.1.1, 6.1, 7.0;
But, if you need to get a new tableView.contentSize after animation (as it was in my case), you must use
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:];
in setCompletionBlock
in order to call your delegate in next runloop.
if you call your delegate directly, without performSelectorOnMainThread, you get old value for tableView.contentSize.

Comment: This seems to work without [tableView beginUpdates] and [tableView endUpdate] method call as well .

Comment: Be careful to not set the completion block after performing your animations. If you set the completion block after, it will be executed immediately.

Comment: Not having used it myself yet, but in iOS 11 a new function `performBatchUpdates` should be preferred over `beginUpdates`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2887515-performbatchupdates

Comment: beginUpdates doesn't need to be after begin

Answer (score 40):

Expanding on [karwag's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13041475/306657), note that on iOS 7, surrounding the CATransaction with a UIView Animation offers control of the table animation duration.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"myAnimationId" context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:10.0]; // Set duration here

[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Complete!");
}];

[myTable beginUpdates];
// my table changes
[myTable endUpdates];

[CATransaction commit];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The UIView animation's duration has no effect on iOS 6. Perhaps iOS 7 table animations are implemented differently, at the UIView level.

Comment: The animation duration appears to be ignored.

Answer (score 31):

That's one hell of a useful trick!
I wrote a UITableView extension to avoid writing CATransaction stuff all the time.

```
import UIKit

extension UITableView {

    /// Perform a series of method calls that insert, delete, or select rows and sections of the table view.
    /// This is equivalent to a beginUpdates() / endUpdates() sequence, 
    /// with a completion closure when the animation is finished.
    /// Parameter update: the update operation to perform on the tableView.
    /// Parameter completion: the completion closure to be executed when the animation is completed.
   
    func performUpdate(_ update: ()->Void, completion: (()->Void)?) {
    
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(completion)

        // Table View update on row / section
        beginUpdates()
        update()
        endUpdates()
    
        CATransaction.commit()
    }

}
```

This is used like so:

```
// Insert in the tableView the section we just added in sections
self.tableView.performUpdate({
    self.tableView.insertSections([newSectionIndex], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.top)

}, completion: {
    // Scroll to next section
    let nextSectionIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: newSectionIndex)
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: nextSectionIndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
})
```

Comment: @GianniCarlo you can do this in ObjC as well

Comment: @CyberMew yes, but creating a Category has always been such a pain, specially due to the long names of the extra files

Answer (score 26):

Shortening [Brent's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18544282/193344), for at least iOS 7 you can wrap this all tersely in a [UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:] call:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
  [self.tableView beginUpdates];
  [self.tableView endUpdates];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  // completion code
}];
```

though, I can't seem to override the default animation curve from anything other than EaseInOut.

Comment: When doing a row insert this way, or @Brent's way, although the duration is respected, the UITableViewRowAnimation does not seem to be respected and always appears to animate top down, even when I specify, for example UITableViewRowAnimationLeft. Testing on iOS 8.4 - anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 24):

Here's a Swift version of [karwag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13041475/306657)

```
CATransaction.begin()
tableView.beginUpdates()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { () -> Void in
    // your code here
}
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexArray, withRowAnimation: .Top)
tableView.endUpdates()
CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 7):

For me I needed this for a collectionView. I've made a simple extension to solve this:

```
extension UICollectionView {

    func reloadSections(sections: NSIndexSet, completion: () -> Void){
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(completion)

        self.reloadSections(sections)

        CATransaction.commit()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As tableView's `performBatch` method is available starting from **iOS 11** only, you can use following extension:

```swift
extension UITableView {
func performUpdates(_ updates: @escaping () -> Void, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.performBatchUpdates({
                updates()
            }, completion: completion)
        } else {
            CATransaction.begin()
            beginUpdates()
            CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
                completion(true)
            }
            updates()
            endUpdates()
            CATransaction.commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Antoine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29122060/8653957) is pretty good – but is for UICollectionView. Here it is for UITableView:

```
extension UITableView {
    func reloadSections(_ sections: IndexSet, with rowAnimation: RowAnimation, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(completion)
        
        self.reloadSections(sections, with: rowAnimation)
        
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Called like so:

```
tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(0), with: .none, completion: {
    // Do the end of animation thing        
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing the problem when tableView is ignoring animation parameters from UIView.animate and using "from up to down" default animation for reloading rows, I've found a strange solution:

You need to:

1. Silence tableView animation
2. Use transitionAnimation instead

Example:

```
let indicesToUpdate = [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)]
UIView.transition(with: self.tableView,
                      duration: 0.5,
                      options: [.transitionCrossDissolve,
                                .allowUserInteraction,
                                .beginFromCurrentState],
                      animations: {
                        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: indicesToUpdate,
                                                      with: .none)
                        }
                      })
```

PS: UIView.transition(..) also has optional completion :)

Answer (score -9):

You could try to wrap the insertRowsAtIndexPath in a

```
- (void)beginUpdates
- (void)endUpdates
```

transaction, then do the flash afterwards.

Comment: See karwag's answer above. You need to solve the problem of what counts as "afterwards".