# Executing callback after insertRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm using the following method to add a new row in my table:

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

However I would like to execute another function after this has finished and the row is effectively present in the table. Is this possible to do?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question which has a more correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832474/uitableview-row-animation-duration-and-completion-callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832474/uitableview-row-animation-duration-and-completion-callback) with a callback:

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            [self performSelector:@selector(showKeyboard:)
                                 withObject:newIndexPath
                                 afterDelay:0.5];
```

There may be a better way though.

Comment: This is not a good solution as it hard-codes a time interval for delay.