# Change duration of UITableView animation (Insert/Delete rows with table beginUpdates)

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview

Is there a way to change the duration of `[table beginUpdates]`/`[table endUpdates]` animations?

This is what I've tried, with no luck:

**Option 1:**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 delay:0.0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration) animations:^{

     [self.tableView beginUpdates];

     [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithArray:indexPaths] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

     [self.tableView endUpdates];


} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

**Option 2:**

```
[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"I actually get called!");
}];

[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:5.0]; //but I don't work

[self.tableView beginUpdates];

[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithArray:indexPaths] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

[self.tableView endUpdates];

[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832474/uitableview-row-animation-duration-and-completion-callback/13041475#13041475 It uses CATransaction to achieve what you want :-)

Comment: I've seen that question. It would work, but my problem is I need the duration specifically, which doesn't work. 

I.e., in option 2 in this question, I need the line `[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:5.0];` to work and it doesn't.

Comment: @TomRedman ever get a good solution for this problem?  I see in the question linked to by Ben above that there now seems to be one that works in iOS 7, but not 6 ...

Comment: @WillMoore, no we've not found a way to reliably modify a tableView's animation duration. I'll have to revisit and see if the duration property solution does work on iOS 7.

Answer (score 16):

Why don't you try UIView animation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInEaseOut animations:^{
  [self.tableView beginUpdates];
  [self.tableView endUpdates];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  // code
}];
```

Comment: Works for me on iOS 7 and iOS 8!

Comment: That's an answer! Works also on iOS 9.

Comment: Works in ios 9 but makes other animations act weird

Comment: @Miniroo maybe there is something else which is wrong with there. The code works on iOS9. Are you sure you are removing the cell correctly? Can you help with your code so I can suggest appropriately.

Comment: The animation duration is ignored for me.

Comment: Works on iOS 10 as well. Why haven't I think of `UIView' class method?!

Answer (score 5):

Here is the **Swift** version of [Gautam Jain's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26080616/5501940) answer :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    // ...
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}) { isFinished in
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@Gautam Jain 's solution is great. However, it has a problem, at least in iOS 9: the completion block will be executed at once but not when the animation completes.

I usually do like below, with a little more code but works better.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
   // completion block
}];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
// updates  
[self.tableView endUpdates];

[CATransaction commit];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```