# How do I change duration for delete animation for cells in table view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
            let cell = CellView(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default , reuseIdentifier: nil)

            let selectView = UIView()
            selectView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"ScrollImageTop1")!)
            cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectView

            return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CellView
                remove(item: indexPath.item)
        }

    func remove(item : Int)
        {
                tableRows -= 1
                tableView1.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)], with: .top)
        }
```

I am unable to understand how to increase animation time for the cell deletion. Please help me with implementing the same here. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There is no such standard iOS API available to achieve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623771/how-to-detect-that-animation-has-ended-on-uitableview-beginupdates-endupdates

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I think its not what he OP asked for, he asked about changing the *duration* of the animation, not detecting it.

Comment: Dupliate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/38890659/5807290

Comment: @AhmadF then its not possible

Answer (score 0):

> How do I change duration for delete animation for cells in table view?

Well there is no official iOS API that allows changing that.

But you can try some workaround which is creating animations on the `UIView`
update the table inside it including the desired animation duration.

you can try something like this

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
 //remove cells or insert them 
self.tableView.endUpdates()
}) { finished in
    // code
}
```

Original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26080616/8192960).