# How to detect when animation completes on UITableViewCell deselect row

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

After selecting a UITableViewCell I call

`[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]`

inside `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

This displays a deselection animation. I'd like to know if there is any way to detect when this animation completes.

Comment: I would try wrapping this statement in a `CATransaction` with a completion block as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832474/uitableview-row-animation-duration-and-completion-callback).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[CATransaction begin];

[tableView beginUpdates];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock: ^{

    NSLog(@"Completion code here");

}];

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
[tableView endUpdates];

[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. FYI to future viewers -- I don't believe the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` calls are strictly necessary in this particular example. Those methods are used to group together multiple actions in a single animation, but since this example only has one deselection action, you could also leave them out here.