# moveRowAtIndexPath How do I know when it is complete?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I'm using `moveRowAtIndexPath` to move certain cells to other positions in my tableview.
I want to add animation when it is completed.
Is there a way to detect that the animation is complete?
Is there a way to control the speed of the animation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView row animation duration and completion callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832474/uitableview-row-animation-duration-and-completion-callback)

Comment: The table view uses core animation to animate the row. Core animations can be nested in a stack of grouped animations, so simply creating your own animation group will give you a core animation object that you can use to provide your own completion callback. See the similar question i flagged yours a duplicate of.

Comment: How is this s duplicate when there they are talking about "insertRowsAtIndexPaths" and I'm talking about "moveRowAtIndexPath" which does the animation automatically?

Comment: It applies to *all* table view animations, not just the one specifically mentioned in the other question. Also, the way duplicates work on stack overflow is when two people ask the same question in a different way, one of them is marked a duplicate of the other. Nothing against you, it's how the system works. :-) In future other people searching might find your answer, and see the link to the other one.