# How to increase animation transition seconds on ios uitableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can we change animation transition speed when deleting a row from `uitableview`, i checked documentation i didn't find any argument where i can specify seconds for transition speed

```
[self.tableViewMeeting deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

Let me know if there is any workaround to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView row animation duration and completion callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832474/uitableview-row-animation-duration-and-completion-callback)

Comment: @Abhishek B, please use the code markup feature when showing code in your question (The"{}" button). It help's with readability, thanks :)

Comment: @fragilecat sure., thanks

Comment: @lihudi its not duplicate of my question, what i am asking is the actual transition animation that happens when the row is deleting is happening very quick so i want to get it further delayed

Comment: @AbhishekB may be it is not a duplicate, but take a look at Brent’s answer that suggests enclosing the animation within a CATransaction block

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
self.tableView.layer.speed = 0.3
```

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `UIView` animation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 
                      delay:0.2 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInEaseOut 
                 animations:^{
                     [self.tableView beginUpdates];
                     [self.tableView endUpdates];  
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // code
                 }
];
```

Comment: your method did half the work but not there are two animations mixing up so i set options to nil and then ran , now only one default animation right to left is happening in tableview i.e withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic , but when there is only one row then it is doing a funny animation flying from center to left kind of.

Answer (score 0):

```
[CATransaction begin];
[tableView beginUpdates];
//...
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock: ^{
    // Code to be executed upon completion
}];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: indexPaths
                 withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[tableView endUpdates];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: where are we defining animation speed here ?

Comment: This answer is copy from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832474/uitableview-row-animation-duration-and-completion-callback and do not answer to this question as do not contain animationDuration