# In a UITableView, how do I know when scrollRectToVisible is complete for a row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

When I select a row in a UITableView, I'm calling `scrollRectToVisible:animated` on the GCRect of the row's frame, and immediately afterwards doing some other animations.  My problem is that I don't know when the animation from `scrollRectToVisible:animated` is complete.

My code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRwoAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:cell.frame animated:YES];

    //more animations here, which I'd like to start only after the previous line is finished! 
}
```

Comment: +1 Good question, but I'm afraid the answer is: you don't know when `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` finishes.

Comment: The answer to the following question might help here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198633/how-can-i-tell-when-a-uitableview-animation-has-finished

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The protocol `UITableViewDelegate` conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`. You can set `BOOL` parameter when you scroll manually and than check it in `scrollViewDidScroll:`

```
BOOL manualScroll;
...
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRwoAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    manualScroll = YES;
    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:cell.frame animated:YES]; 
}
...
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (manualScroll)
    {
        manualScroll = NO;
        //Do your staff
    }

}
```

Don't forget to set `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: That's pretty hacky, but it seems like it would work, and the best you can do given the framework.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: there is `dragging` property on UIScrollView which does the manual scroll tracking for you

Answer (score 16):

I ran across this `UIScrollViewDelegate` method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   // Do your stuff.
}
```

Only called for animated scrolls. Not called for touch-based scrolls. Seems to work great.

Comment: Nice, note however is the rect is already visible this method will not be called

Answer (score 9):

An easier way is to encapsulate the scrolling code in a UIView animateWith[...] block, like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:cell.frame animated:NO];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // Some completion code
}];
```

Note that animated == NO in the scrollRectToVisible:animated: method.

Comment: This should be the anwser