# UITableView check animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, uianimation

How can I check when animation finished.

I use this method:

[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

Thanks all!

Comment: You want to know, when a non-animation is finished?!

Comment: yes (also it should be other animation)

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198633/how-can-i-tell-when-a-uitableview-animation-has-finished, which also has a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) to the animation class reference. I think that the function

```
-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
```

is the one that you looking for.

Comment: thanks for response! :) but how I can set my table that the my table call method animationDidStop?